# tf.linalg.eigh extremely slow on GPU - normal?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I just found the culprit that slowed down my code on the GPU: `tf.linalg.eigh()`.

The Idea is quite simple: I create - let's say - 87.000 4x4 Hermitian matrices and want to get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of them. For this I have a placeholder `matrix` of shape [87.000,4,4] which I feed into `tf.linalg.eigh(matrix)`. I run the Session and feed these matrices as input (the matrix has data type complex64) and want as output the eigenvalues.

This took on a 8 core CPU less than 0.04s, while the GPU needed 19s - on it took NumPy roughly 0.4s.

So my question is: Why is the `tf.linalg.eigh()` so slow on the GPU even if one gives large batch sizes. Even if the diagonalization of one matrix can not be parallelised efficiently, the GPU should still be much faster in the case of thousands of matrices...

Can one somehow fix this or do I have to switch from GPU to CPU for this operation?

To the code:

the imports

```py
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter

import tensorflow as tf

config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count = {'GPU': 1})

sess = tf.Session(config=config)

import time
```

the building of the tf parts

```py
matrix=tf.placeholder(tf.complex64,shape[None,87,4,4],name="matrix")

eigenval,eigenvec=tf.linalg.eigh(tf.linalg.adjoint(matrix))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess.run(init)

complex_matrix=np.ones((10000,87,4,4))+1j*np.ones((batch_net,path_length,num_orbits,num_orbits))
```

running the operation and measuring the time

```py
t1=time.time()
sess.run(eigenvec,feed_dict={matrix: complex_matrix, eigenvalues_true: eigenvalues })
print(time.time()-t1)
```

Comment: Could you add your exact code?

Comment: Sure, I am sorry for not doing this right away. I have to mention, that `´eigenval,eigenvec=tf.linalg.eigh(tf.linalg.adjoint(matrix))´ is part of some larger graph but apparently the main bottleneck. Before this, there is a network and after this operation there are several small post processing operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little experimenting, i think in this case it's better to place this op on CPU. The point is PCI-GPU communication is a bottleneck here, so you simply can't get good GPU utilization rate. Although this overhead can be made smaller by generating random martix with TF op on GPU

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    matrix = tf.random.uniform((87000,4,4), minval=0.1, maxval=0.99, dtype=tf.float32)
    eigenval,eigenvec=tf.linalg.eigh(matrix)
```

It only allows for about 40% reduced computation time on my system, which is still way slower than CPU. 
Also you could try spliting tensor into equal chunks, performing `linalg.eigh` and concatenating results, but this also gives almost no improvement

```
matrix = tf.random.uniform((87000,4,4), minval=0.1, maxval=0.99, dtype=tf.float32)
result = tf.concat([tf.linalg.eigh(x)[1] for x in tf.split(matrix, 1000, axis=0)], axis=0)
```

I also noted that scaling of `linalg.eigh` performed on CPU is approximately logarithmic, while GPU operation is seemingly linear. Hope this helps!

A little update. Looks like operation `SelfAdjointEigV2` is not even supported by XLA compiler, so this code

```
matrix = tf.random.uniform((87000, 4, 4), minval=0.1, maxval=0.99, dtype=tf.float32)
def xla_test(matrix):
    eigenval, eigenvec = tf.linalg.eigh(matrix)
    return eigenvec

y = xla.compile(xla_test, inputs=[matrix])
```

throws 'Detected unsupported operations' error

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I was afraid of hearing, that there is now way to make it work faster on the GPU. I am still very curious, why the GPU-PCI communication is the bottleneck. In the original code I gave an ANN an input batch, which in the end after several operations lead to this matrix. Everything except of the beginning should be on the GPU.

Comment: I guess the answer may lie deep in TF's internals, in particular implementation. Anyway, it's a good practice to  optimize TF code by placing operations on different devices, as long as it gives adequate performance.

Comment: So I am quite new to the low level api (uses Keras before). Is there anything a novice should keep in mind when putting the network on the GPU and the parts above on the CPU - especially when the parts on top contribute to the Loss as numerical factor. Btw: thanks for your help so far, it is really appreciated!

Comment: The main recommendation is to place any preprocessing an cpu. other things are mostly case specific. see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/overview and https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets. And if my answer was helpful, consider accepting it.